# Can you whitelist subdomains in the gmail-addons manifest?

Tags: gmail-addons

The documentation states we need to whitelist all base URLs we want the add-on to open.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/manifests#whitelisting_urls

Our app uses subdomains per customer. I would like to whitelist our base url plus all subdomains off of it.

Does anyone know if that is possible?

Comment: Have you already considered implementing a redirector, so you don't have to list all possible URLs? We are facing a similar issue for our use case.

Answer (score 0):

you should implement a single api implemented in our server for which you can pass these subdomain urls and api at the server side should get these url from request params. Then using any http library you can make a call to that subdomain url.

With this approach only one url has to be whitelisted which is our server api url.

This is how we are doing the whitelisting problem for both opening urls and UrlFetchApp.